# Как вместо текста отправить только кнопки выбора?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Телеграм бот на python. Задача реализовать ответ на сообщение пользователя в виде кнопочного меню. Использую библиотеку python-telegram-bot. Для ответа использую метод reply_text, вероятно ответ можно реализовать каким-то другим методом, но я не знаю каким.

```
inline_buttons = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
    inline_keyboard=[
    [InlineKeyboardButton('Order', callback_data='order')],
    [InlineKeyboardButton('About us', callback_data='about')]
    ],
)

update.message.reply_text(
    text = 'some text',
    reply_markup=inline_buttons,
)
```

Пробовал оставить параметр текст пустым, text = ' ', но в этом случае возникает ошибка: telegram.error.BadRequest: Message must be non-empty

Как это исправить или есть другой способ отправки ответа пользователю?